# Отборный или отборочный?

Tags: лексика

**Правильно ли употреблено слово "отборный" в следующем примере:**

**Отборный кинопоказ** таких фильмов как «Армаггедон», «Перл-Харбор», «Годзилла» и других ― обеспечивает рейтинг воскресенья. [Мила Кузина. Константин Эрнст: «Мы научились не получать бюджетные средства» (2002) // «Известия», 2002.09.24]

**Какое значение** (и почему) имеют слова "отборный и отборочный", **могут ли они быть синонимами?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, в этом интервью "*отборный показ*" - попытка уйти от выражения "*отборные фильмы*", которое с некоторым уничижением приравнивает художественные произведения к однотипной материальной продукции (вроде зерна или фруктов), и кратко высказать смысл, что (по обыкновению) в определённый день **покажут специально отобранные фильмы**, чтобы обеспечить достаточно высокий рейтинг канала. Можно лишь предположить существование профессионального жаргонизма "*отборный показ*" (показ на основе тщательного отбора материала). В обычной речи такое недопустимо (отбирается объект для показа, а не сам показ, как можно заключить). Слово "*отборочный*" здесь не подходит: по смыслу это был бы "показ с целью отбора".

**P.S.** *Бельчиков, Панюшева. Словарь паронимов русского языка, 2002*

**отборный** - отобранный, самый хороший

**отборочный** - отбирающий, производящий отбор

Подробнее (страницы с полной статьёй):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=MfnLAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA320&img=1&zoom=3&ots=82A1MieGvw&sig=ACfU3U2hB8WMbRcW-1kvn71VA6j6Gr50OA&w=1280

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=MfnLAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA321&img=1&zoom=3&ots=82A1MieGvw&sig=ACfU3U10IJwxqY10pm1jYmfmJ_fkFEWOfg&w=1280

Comment: У нас сейчас не только зерно отборное, но и фильмы тоже, например: "Отборные фильмы ужасов собраны в данном топе, смотрите и бойтесь! ...Лучшие и только отборные фильмы и мультфильмы! В этом разделе мы припасли для вас отборную научную фантастику, фэнтези, фантасмагорию".  Но вот отборный (лучший)  кинопоказ - это нечто странное. А  отборочный кинопоказ  -  это показ уже отобранных  по какому-то признаку фильмов, не обязательно конкурсный показ  с целью отбора.

Comment: "Отборные фильмы (ужасов)" - грамматически возможное выражение, с ужасами и чем-нибудь нехорошим вполне сочетается, но в позитивном смысле к фильмам оно плохо подходит; "отборные шедевры кино", как и "отборная классика" (вместо "избранных") звучит вульгарно. При отборе по признаку, скорее, "выборочный" (в кинотеатрах планируется выборочный показ фильмов Венецианского фестиваля).

Comment: (Энциклопедический словарь 2009) _ОТБО́РОЧНЫЙ -ая, -ое. Созданный, служащий для отбора. О-ая комиссия. О-ые соревнования._

Comment: Выборка делается по каким-то признакам,  это не обязательно качество, а "отборные фильмы" воспринимаются однозначно как лучшие, даже "избранная классика" только условно понятна. Вот и приходится рекламщикам (рекламистам) пользоваться вульгарным словом.

Comment: "Специально _отобранные_ (по признаку) фильмы" чем плохо?